# how do i force NTP client to symc from the server (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, ntp, task-scheduler, time-synchronization

i need to make my NTP server to force my NTP clients to sync with him once n a few hours .

until now i used the "task scheduler" to set a task in each client to sync with the server but now i have to many clients to do that so i wanted to know if there is any way to force the clients to sync with the server once in a few hours .
all the computers i am using (server and clients ) are windows 7 64 bits

Comment: What you're doing is not necessary, because the OS already has a service to manage time sync. Is there a more specific problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how NTP works. The NTP server is really just a passive server. Everything is dictated by the clients.

For example, you can use authentication with NTP, but the server can't force the clients to use authentication. The server is happy to serve up NTP to unauthenticated clients. The clients are the ones which must ask for authenticated NTP.

If you want clients to get NTP on a periodic basis, you must configure the clients to do so.